# "I can tell you more about myself"

Tags: prepositions, pronouns

I have a simple question. Can I say "I can tell you more about myself" like this

Posso dirti di più circa me.

The main doubts I have is if I can use "di più" like this, if circa is right and if I should use "me" or "mi" (I might have imagined it, but I thought I read somewhere that me is used after a preposition).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Italian I use "*posso dirti di più su di me*" or "*posso dirti di più di me*". Or even better "*posso dirti qualcosa in più su di/di me*" that is "I can tell you something more about myself".

Comment: Yes I wondered about ..."di più di"... can you use "su" in general to mean 'about' or 'regarding'?

Comment: About it's "circa" when you talk abount quantities. Probably in other cases too, but now I dont't know. When you are speaking about someone or something it's "su/di" or "riguardo"

Answer (score 4):

Not a grammatical issue  but a more common translation is:

> - Posso dirti di più di me/su di me.

Using *circa* I'd probably say

> - Posso dirti di più circa me stesso. (Not a common use of "circa" anyway)